# Como fazer um vídeo iniciar e reiniciar automaticamente?

Tags: javascript, html5, css3, html5-video

Boa noite, estou fazendo um site e no meio dele coloquei um vídeo que quero que inicie e reinicie automaticamente sem que o usuário precise clicar no botão de play ou no de reiniciar, alguém pode me ajudar obs: já tentei usar o atributo autoplay e não deu certo? Aki está o código:

Pokemon Generations

```
<body style="background-image: url(Fundo/fundo_pokemon_branco.jpg)">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg ml-5 mr-5 navbar-dark mb-5" style="background-color:#38102b" > 
        <div class="container">
            <a class="navbar-brand h1 mb-0" href="site_inicial.htm"><img src="Logo/shining_legends.png"></a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSite">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span> 
            </button>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse " id="navbarSite" > 
                <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#"><button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-warning" class="ml-1"><img src="Icones/icone_personagens_gold.png" >Personagens</button></a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#"><button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-warning" class="ml-1"><img src="Icones/icone_comojogar_gold.png" >Como jogar</button></a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#"><button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-warning" class="ml-1"><img src="Icones/icone_jogar_gold1.png" >Jogar</button></a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#"><button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-warning" class="ml-1"><img src="Icones/icone_atualizacoes_gold.png" >Atualizações</button></a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item mr-5"><a class="nav-link" href="#"><button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-warning" class="ml-1"><img src="Icones/icone_quemsou_gold.png" >Quem Sou</button></a></li>

                    <li class="nav-item " id="charmander"><a class="navbar-brand h1 mb-0 pulo" target="_blank" href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC6VdsMMnL-GdcoKc9qZEtQA?disable_polymer=true"><img src="Icones/icone_charmander.png"></a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="navbar-brand h1 mb-0 pulo " target="_blank" href="http://api.whatsapp.com/send?1=pt_BR&phone=5584996011922"><img src="Icones/icone_bulbasaur.png"></a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="navbar-brand h1 mb-0 pulo" target="_blank" href="https://twitter.com/LegendsShining"><img src="Icones/icone_squirtle.png"></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>

        </div>
    </nav>

    <video controls src="Fundo/greninja.mp4" type="video/mp4 controls"  height="180%"width="100%">  

    </video>

</body>
```

Comment: Você conseguiu fazer reproduzir automaticamente quando a página abre e quando o vídeo termina não repete?

Comment: Eu não tava conseguindo fazer nada, mas já deu certo aqui, mesmo assim obrigado :)

Comment: O que eu ainda tô em dúvida é pq as vezes o vídeo carrega e as vezes n

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bom você poderia fazer para o vídeo iniciar e reiniciar dessa maneira.

```
    <video autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop" controls src="Fundo/greninja.mp4" type="video/mp4 controls" height="180%"width="100%">  

    </video>
```

O atributo `autoplay` é para o vídeo ser reproduzido automaticamente e já o atributo `loop` é para ficar iniciando o vídeo automaticamente quando ele acabar. Porém o *Google Chrome* não permite mais que vídeo com som seja reproduzido automaticamente nas páginas, leia [AQUI](https://canaltech.com.br/navegadores/atualizacao-do-chrome-bloqueia-automaticamente-reproducao-automatica-de-videos-110476/). A não ser que o vídeo esteja mudo.
Mas você pode alterar isso na sua máquina colocando o seguinte na sua URL *chrome://flags/* e aperte enter o *Google Flags* é aonde você encontrara varios recursos do *Google Chrome* que são experimentais e é aqui que você vai ativar o `autoplay`. Pesquise na barra *Search flags* por *autoplay* e ache por *Autoplay policy* e no botão a direita que provavelmente está marcado como *Default* marque a opção *No user gesture is required.* e depois reinicie o navegador e o atributo `autoplay` deve estar funcionando corretamente, mas esse recurso irar está disponivel apenas para você. Caso você queira fazer com que o vídeo seja reproduzido automaticamente e iniciado usando *JavaScript* também é fácil.

Coloque um `id` no seu vídeo com o nome, por exemplo `video`.

```
        <video id="video" controls src="Fundo/greninja.mp4" type="video/mp4"  height="180%"width="100%">  

        </video>
```

Depois use *JavaScript*.

```
<script>

   window.addEventListener("load", function ()
   {
       let video = window.document.querySelector("#video");
       video.play();
       video.loop = true;
   });

</script>
```

Nesse trecho de código foi adicionado um evento de `load` no `window` para que quando a página for carregada chame uma função anônima, depois tem uma variável `video` fazendo referência ao `id="video"` e a função `play()` para iniciar o vídeo automaticamente e o `loop = true` para inicializar o vídeo automaticamente quando ele acabar.

Answer (score 3):

Solução nada bonita mas eficaz:

```js
document.getElementById('vid').play();
```

```html
<video controls src="https://ia800701.us.archive.org/26/items/SampleVideo1280x7205mb/SampleVideo_1280x720_5mb.mp4" type="video/mp4 controls"  height="180%"width="100%" autoplay loop muted playsinline id="vid">  
    </video>
```

Resumindo, alguns navegadores exigem muted para o autoplay funcionar; o playsinline evita que o vídeo redimensione e o javascript ativa o play se nada funcionar.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda :)

Comment: por nada, estamos juntos!